# Implement different layouts for a (part of a) web page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, flexbox

I want to implement a coding playground. At the moment, I use `flex-box` to define the position of different panels. Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qujutih/17/edit?html,css,js,output), and its html part:

```
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="col" id="html-panel">
    <p>html</p>
  </div>
  <div class="handle">
    <div class="handle-inner"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="css-panel">
    <p>css</p>
  </div>
  <div class="handle">
    <div class="handle-inner"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="js-panel">
    <p>javascript</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

(to make it a playground, I add `textarea` inside each `panel` (e.g., `html-textarea` in `html-panel`), and combine the content of the 3 textareas to return an output. The playground reacts to every change to the content in textareas: I choose to use an AngularJS controller to do so, rather than JQuery event handlers.)

Now, I am wondering how to realise different layouts without repeating too much code. Like [Liveweave](http://www.liveweave.com) proposing 4 layouts (see right bottom corner) to users, I want to propose displaying for example

- horizontally the 3 panels as what looks like at the moment
- vertically the 3 panels
- 1 on the left and 2 on the right
- 2 on the left and 1 on the right

So what's the best approach/structure/tool to implement this?

To share maximum, should we realise this with 1 common `.html`, 1 common `.js` and 4 `.css` files? Then, we just need to choose different `.css` file for different layouts?

Comment: Why not use a single-page application framework like Angular or React?

Comment: This is why I have added `angularjs` tag... so `angularjs` could do this? Where could I get more instructions to just implement these different views?

Comment: Angular will facilitate the structure for just using 1 html file. Now, as far as 1 js file you'll hve to bundle the code (GulpJs, GruntJs, Webpack are good tools fr this). I am on my mobile so I can't really write a good answer, but you should definitely try it out.

Comment: why not keep it simple.  This could be done with just css and js.  Use js to change the class of each panel and use css to position each class/panel appropriately

Comment: @DCR I see what you mean... So I would like to what's the conventional way to implement this. For instance, did liveweave use frameworks or just css + js? I checked their front page, i didn't see `angular.js` there.

Comment: @Thomas  I think it's pretty straight forward.  Start by creating your html template and then use this one template with different css files to get the results you're looking for.  Once you have that, combine the separate css files and right the js to change div classes as needed.  In terms of lime weave I'm not sure what they are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some research, this certainly can be done by nested views / UI-Router / AngularUI / Angular JS. And we will be able to define one html file per layout.

But I will first go for what @DCR suggested: by only JS and CSS. Because it is simpler, also because JS allows us to inject html, e.g., by `innerHTML`. Therefore, I could inject 4 html strings for 4 layouts. Inside the 4 html strings, there could be same class names, which enable some sharing of styling in CSS and functions (eg, splitter-dragging) in JS.